# PHP - Predict next number and detect a pattern of a sequence of numbers

Tags: php, math, numbers, sequence, predict

Hi im making a script to predict the next number in a secuence but i cant get it to run...

What i need? A script to predict the next number in a secuence like Maths questions for childs, but more extensive.

- Example 1:

  ```
  3 > 6 > 9
  ```

Here would be `+ 3 + 3`, the pattern is `"+3"`

- Example 2 (we will make it more difficult):

  ```
  4 > 10 > 5 > 11 > 6
  ```

Here is `+ 6 - 5  + 6 - 5`, the pattern is `"+6-5"`

- Well... Next example, would make it very hard:

  ```
  2 > 16 > 8 > 13 > 104 > 52 > 57 > 456
  ```

Here is `+ 14 - 8 + 5 + 91 - 52 + 5 + 399....` but the pattern is `"* 8 / 2 + 5"`

The scripts needs to return the next number "possible" and the detected pattern.

This is for educational purposes.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-finding-rule.html

Answer (score 3):

I have took this as a challenge to write it in the pure PHP, so my result class is this:

```
class Predict {
    private $nums = array();
    private $rawPattern = array();

    function __construct($nums) {
        $this->nums = $nums;
        $this->createPattern();
    }

    private function patternPart($num) {
        if($num >= 0) {
            $patternPart = "+{$num}";
        } else {
            $patternPart = "{$num}";
        }

        return $patternPart;
    }

    private function createPattern() {
        foreach($this->nums as $key => $num) {
            if($key > 0) {
                $prev = $this->nums[$key - 1];
                $diff = $num - $prev;

                $this->rawPattern[] = $this->patternPart($diff);
            }
        }
    }

    function getPattern($del = ' ') {
        $first = reset($this->rawPattern);

        // When all values are same just print the first one
        if(count(array_unique($this->rawPattern)) === 1 && end($this->rawPattern) === $first) {
            return $first;
        } else {
            $resultPattern = array();
            $patternToAppend = array();
            $doCheckIndex = 0;

            foreach($this->rawPattern as $key => $part) {
                if($key == 0) {
                    $resultPattern[] = $part;
                } else {
                    $checkNum = $this->rawPattern[$doCheckIndex];

                    if($checkNum == $part) {
                        $patternToAppend[] = $part;
                        $doCheckIndex++;
                    } else {
                        $patternToAppend[] = $part;
                        $doCheckIndex = 0;

                        if(!empty($patternToAppend)) {
                            $resultPattern = array_merge($resultPattern, $patternToAppend);
                            $patternToAppend = array();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return implode($del, $resultPattern);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried it with your values, so these are results:

```
$nums1 = new Predict(array(3, 6, 9));
$nums2 = new Predict(array(4, 10, 5, 11, 6));
$nums3 = new Predict(array(2, 16, 8, 13, 104, 52, 57, 456));

echo $nums1->getPattern(); // prints +3
echo $nums2->getPattern(); // prints +6 -5
echo $nums3->getPattern(); // prints +14 -8 +5 +91 -52 +5 +399
```

Well I'm not the best dev, but seems to be working. Just try more options or whatever and when it will not work let me know (maybe I will find some time again).

Comment: WoW Thats fast! This class is good for sums and subtracts and is what im looking for! But needs to detect divisions and multiplications...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I don't know how now :D I will look at it in the evening when I come home. Just put some examples so I will can test that cases.